# Use the contents of a cell to refer to a sheet name

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I've a workbook with several sheets. The first, "Chart", is a nicely formatted sheet filled with data from the second sheet "current". The formulas, 72 of them, are like:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2&C2,Current.$D$2:$F$73,2,0),"")
```

There are numerous other sheets with previous versions of "current", like "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", etc. I want to be able to put text into a cell in "Chart", such as "current" or "Sep", and have the formulas use the contents of that cell to reference the sheet name, as in

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2&C2,whateverValueIsInTheCell.$D$2:$F$73,2,0),"")
```

So how to get text in a cell to be recognized as the name of a sheet, in a reference in a formula?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`INDIRECT()`](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDIRECT) to address the cells by a string. Something along the lines of

```
...INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A1,".$D$2:$F$73"))...
```

if `A1` is the cell you want to put the sheet name in.